# VueJS Promise.all issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

I am trying to implement a promise-based logic on an ansync data fetch in VueJS.

I used to have that logic first:

```
if (influencer.suggested?.length && url.length) {
    const [ interactions, suggested_ids ] = await Promise.all([
        $axios.$get(url),
        store.dispatch('influencers/FETCH_SET', influencer.suggested),
    ]);
    return ({
        interactions,
        suggested_ids,
    });
}
```

..but the `if` conditions are bound together and this is not what I want as one of them could be false but I still need the other one to be executed.

Here is my latest implementation:

```
        if (store.getters['user/is_band'])
            url = '/band/history/?influencer_id=' + influencer.id;
        
        const interactionPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (url.length) {
                $axios.$get(url);
                resolve();
            } else
                reject();
        })

        const suggestionPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (influencer.suggested?.length) {
                store.dispatch('influencers/FETCH_SET', influencer.suggested);
                resolve();
            } else 
                reject();
        })

        const [ interactions, suggested_ids ] = await Promise.all([
            interactionPromise,
            suggestionPromise,
        ]);

        return ({
            interactions,
            suggested_ids,
        });
```

It seems to me that if one of the promises is false, it should `reject` then pass to the other one but that's not the case..

Also if `if (store.getters['user/is_band'])` is `false` everything falls appart and the app just crash..

How can I execute this `Promise.all` without crash if one of the promises is rejected?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would solve this problem:

```
// We will assign these values later
let interactions, suggested_ids;

if (store.getters['user/is_band']) {
    try {
        interactions = await $axios.$get('/band/history/?influencer_id=' + influencer.id);
    } catch (ex) {
        // Promise rejected
    }
}

if (influencer.suggested?.length) {
    try {
        suggested_ids = await store.dispatch('influencers/FETCH_SET', influencer.suggested);
    } catch (ex) {
        // Promise rejected
    }
}

return {
    interactions,
    suggested_ids
};
```

I do not think `Promise.all` is the right way to go here because it wraps all Promises and returns one resolve or reject state. So either all Promises resolve or (if one is rejected) the entire `Promise.all` is rejected.

By splitting it up you retain more control about how you handle each promise.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I thought I could have one promise rejected without rejected the whole pipe with `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 1):

> Promise.all is rejected if any of the elements are rejected.  and its possible to change this behaviour by handling possible rejections

```js
(async function() {

const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(() => resolve('p1_delayed_resolution'), 1000); 
}); 

const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject('p2_immediate_rejection');
});


const [p1Result, p2Result] = await Promise.all([
  p1.catch(error => error ),
  p2.catch(error => error ),
]);

console.log(p1Result, p2Result)
}());
```

in your case it will be something like

```
const [ interactions, suggested_ids ] = await Promise.all([
        $axios.$get(url).catch(e => e),
        store.dispatch('influencers/FETCH_SET', influencer.suggested).catch(e => e),
    ]);
```

Comment: @Wizzardzz it would be nice if you reject with error message, so that you can easily track